# Having trouble installing and importing tensorflow in Python 3.6

Tags: python, tensorflow

I am using windows, Python 3.6.7, and conda 4.5.12

Here is what I've done so far:

-since tensorflow only works on Python 3.4, 3.5, and 3.6 I created an environment in anaconda prompt `conda create -n py36 python=3.6 anaconda`

- activated the environment `conda activate py36`
- attempted to install tensorflow using anaconda but it failed:

  (py36) `C:\Users\jim>conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow`

Solving environment: failed

CondaUpgradeError: This environment has previously been operated on by a conda version that's newer
than the conda currently being used. A newer version of conda is required.
  target environment location: C:\Users\jim\Anaconda3\envs\py36
  current conda version: 4.5.12
  minimum conda version: 4.6

- so I just installed it with pip and it worked:

  (py36) C:\Users\jim>pip install tensorflow
- [this screenshot confirms that tensorflow is installed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvXCi.png)
- went into anaconda navigator, switched to py36, and opened up a jupyter notebook (doesn't work in Spyder either), and got this:

  `import tensorflow as tf`

---

ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy.core._multiarray_umath'

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.multiarray failed to import

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

SystemError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
~\Anaconda3\envs\py36\lib\importlib_bootstrap.py in _find_and_load(name, import_)

SystemError:  returned a result with an error set

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core._multiarray_umath failed to import

---

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
ImportError: numpy.core.umath failed to import

and then the kernel dies and it resets.

Any thoughts on what might be wrong?

Comment: numpy is installed ;

Comment: yes it is: numpy 1.15.4 py36h19fb1c0_0 numpy-base 1.15.4 py36hc3f5095_0

Answer (score 2):

You can try these steps:

```
    1.conda create --name tf_env python=3.6

    2. conda activate tf_env

    3. conda install -c conda-forge tensorflow=1.12.0

    4. Try importing tensorflow 

    5. conda deactivate
```

Answer (score 1):

create tensorflow environment than active it:

```
conda create -n tensorflow_env tensorflow
    conda activate tensorflow_env
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I was having *trouble importing `keras`* after running `conda install keras`

It worked when I upgraded my numpy installation. [This site](https://github.com/alpacahq/pylivetrader/issues/73) suggests `numpy` version 1.16 will work better, and that `pip install` may be needed (vs `conda install`):

`pip install numpy==1.16`

Also, after installing `conda install keras`, some of my colleagues had a different error; an error like "Could not find module named `tensorflow`". We fixed this by installing `tensorflow`:  `pip install tensorflow`